# Assigning multiple public ips for a website

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, web-server, load-balancing

if we are having 3 webservers with same domain name and each with different public ip.
Will this setup bring minimal load balancing.

as we do a lookup of google.com it get resolved to 10+ ip.can this setup can bring a similar setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one common way of load balancing called a DNS round robin - basically using DNS to give out different IP addresses to different people.

You need to make sure your web site is designed to be load balanced in this way as it means that if a client refreshes its DNS cache itbetween requests, it may get a different IP and so send subsequent requests to a different server.

Generally web sites that serve static content or don't make use of any stored state are suitable for this sort of load balancing